# Restrict access to a folder using c#

Tags: c#, security, folder-security

There is a folder that gets created in public documents while installing the WPF app. It contains downloaded data while we run the app. I do not want the user to access that folder. If there is any way to restrict the user to access that folder? I do not want to encrypt the content.

Comment: Have you tried using [Directory.SetAccessControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8)? But if your program is running under the context of the user, then that means they have permissions to change security settings.

Comment: Is this a security issue or just a nuisance issue? You won't be able to truly lock down those files, not even with encrypting them client-side. You'd have to move that information to an external service.

Comment: @Crowcoder It's a security issue. Users download some content from the app and it gets saved in a folder on the user system. We need to restrict the user somehow.

Comment: Don't let them download the content in the first place.

Comment: If the app running under the context of the user can read the files then the user can too. If you need more security than obfuscation you have to move that data to a location the user has no control or access to other than through effective AuthZ and AuthN